Natural way to extend Lebesgue measure concept on normed space
I will ask two questions that involve proposition 1.15 and theorem 1.16 from Follands' real analysis book.
First question:
Folland constructs the Lebesbgue Stieltjes measure in $\mathbb{R}$, and I already know that it is possible to construct the Lebesbgue Stieltjes measure in $\mathbb{R}ˆn$ by extending the statements of proposition 1.15 and theorem 1.16 in the most natural. My question is the following:
Is it possible to construct the Lebesgue Stielsjes measure on $\mathbb{R}ˆn$ starting from the Lebesgue Stieltjes measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and somehow extending it to the sigma algebra product?
Second question:
An arbitrary normed space is locally connected and locally convex. So if E is a normed space, then:

Every point of $E$ has a local basis composed of convex sets.
If $A$ is open in $E$, then there exists a unique partition of $A$ constituted by open connected sets that are closed in $A$.

Suppose that $E$ is a normed space such that:

1° If $A$ is open in $E$, then any convex subset of $A$ that is open in $E$ is closed in $A$
2° every disjoint collection of open subsets of $E$ in $E$ is countable.

(I don't know if the 1° property is always valid or if it is valid by adding a specific topological property as a condition). The 2° property is valid if $E$ has a countable dense subset (for exemple, if $E$ is Lindelöf)
Since convex implies connectedness, then if $E$ has such properties, then we conclude that:

if $A$ is open in $E$, then there exists a unique partition of $A$ that consists of open covex sets that are closed in $A$, and this partition is countable.

Thus, if $E$ has this property, we can probably extend the concept of Lebesgue measure (not lebesgue-stielsjtes, due to monotonicity) to $E$, since this is the property that Folland uses to prove proposition 1.15 to construct the Lebesgue measure.
I think that if we put $\mu_0(\bigcup(u_j,v_j)) = \sum(||u_j-v_j||)$, (where $(u_j,v_j)$ is the segment of extrems $u_j$ and $v_j$) on proposition 1.15 we can get an natural extension of the lebesgue measure on $E$. And probably this measure would have good properties such the Lebesgue measure on \mathbb{R} has, such invariance under homotety and translation.
I'll be grateful if someone can help me formalize all this, and perhaps find a good condition for a normed space $E$ own the 1° property.

To answer your first point: yes. First try and prove $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^n$. Then, using this, try and prove $\mathcal{L}^n =  \prod_{i = 1}^n \mathcal{L}$ by using Dynkin's theorem. Here $\mathcal{L}$ is the $1$-dim lebesgue measure, and $\mathcal{L}^n$ the $n$-dim lebesgue measure induced by cathedory's theorem via the natural outer measure $\mu_0(\prod (a_i, b_i)) = \prod |b_i - a_i|$

thank you, i got it.
